# createWriteStream and path is not working

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create an invoice and for some reason this below line isn't working:

```
document.pdfkitDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./file.pdf'))
```

maybe a syntax problem , I dont really know it's been copied from npm
any suggestions ?

this is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var pdfInvoice = require('pdf-invoice')

router.post('/add', function(req, res) {

  const document = pdfInvoice({
    company: {
      phone: '(99) 9 9999-9999',
      email: 'company@evilcorp.com',
      address: 'Av. Companhia, 182, Água Branca, Piauí',
      name: 'Evil Corp.',
    },
    customer: {
      name: 'Elliot Raque',
      email: 'raque@gmail.com',
    },
    items: [
      {amount: 50.0, name: 'XYZ', description: 'Lorem ipsum dollor sit amet', quantity: 12},
      {amount: 12.0, name: 'ABC', description: 'Lorem ipsum dollor sit amet', quantity: 12},
      {amount: 127.72, name: 'DFE', description: 'Lorem ipsum dollor sit amet', quantity: 12},
    ],
  })



  docucment.generate() // triggers rendering
  document.pdfkitDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./file.pdf'))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `docucment.generate()` has a typo, it should be `document.generate()`.

Comment: No problem. :) If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: ofcourse , I just had to wait few mins before I could click on it :)